# STM32L031G6 Power on Reset Issue

Tags: power-supply, stm32, brownout

I currently have a PCB that I designed using a STM32L031G6 MCU. I have designed many boards with STM32 chips as well as other MCU's. Typically I have a simple cap and pullup resistor on the RST line to help with power on reset and/or brownout. I have never had an issue before this board.

I have two of these made, as they communicate together. One is powered from a 3v3 benchtop supply, the other from 3V from AA batteries. Both of them will only start properly around 10-20% of the time. I have to power cycle many times to get it to finally start correctly. If I reset or program it from my STLink, it starts perfect every time.

I know I can use a POR supervisor and that should fix it, but it is surprising to me that in 10+ designs I have had with STM32 chips, it has never been an issue. It's also tough because this is a low cost design, and we really don't have the BOM cost for a $0.30+ part..

We have changed the Brownout reset threshold level's using option bytes, and it didn't have a large impact. Also changed C9 to a 10uF and nothing changed either.

Any thoughts?[image]

Comment: Hi, Just to help understand the limits before I consider writing an answer: (a) Are you able to separate the two MCUs and investigate just one to begin with? (It's not clear how they are connected, so this might not be a sensible question - can't tell yet...) (b) Are you able to supply the full schematic? (c) Are you prepared to sacrifice at least one board during the investigation? (d) Was there any working prototype before these intermittently working boards? If so, do you still have access to that working prototype? (e) Can you supply PCB layout images? Thanks.

Comment: (f) Which STLink are you using? (real or clone or ... ?) They don't all work the same and can have different effects on the target. (g) Can you supply a photo of the failing hardware setup, in case we can spot anything of concern on the actual hardware? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson a) Yes, the communicate over a spi - > rf chip. b) No. But it's quite simple. Spi buss, few leds and buzzers, no regulators or anything. C) I suppose I can. d) No. e) No, but again, it's quite simple. f) Real, Stlink V3. g) Again, no sorry.

Comment: @KyleHunter Can you write a *specific question*? it's unclear what your problem is. Are you having problems with the reset line?

Comment: @KyleHunter - Thanks for replying. I've written an answer within those limits (as I understand them). Can you please read the comment by *jonk* below my answer, and see if that was your intended meaning about the startup problem, i.e. could a communications problem be the cause, because your test requires the two boards to communicate for success of your test? Or is your test for "correct startup" self-contained within each board, without relying on the other board (linked over RF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I made a rookie stack move - posting a question before fully understanding my issue..

So the problem wasn't with the POR. Right as the STM32 powered on, I was then enabling the SPI -> RF device, which was tied to the STM32 interrupt driven. The STM32 starts at ~1.8V, while the SPI device needs 2.8V. So the STM32 started up before the other device, which when enabled incorrectly (too early), broke the interrupt logic, causing both devices to hang.

Added a 100ms delay before talking to the device, and it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think that also explains why it worked consistently after a reset from the debugger (either a reset on its own, or a reset after programming) as that would occur when the STM32 and RF device were both fully powered-up. With hindsight, this suggests that pulling NRST low manually with the STM32 "hanging" (debugger removed) should also have worked. My answer would have pointed in this direction too, since my suggested "blink LED" test would have worked, telling you that the problem was *not* with the POR (as initially suspected).

Answer (score 4):

Within the limits explained in comments on the question, here is some analysis.

(Note: From your earlier comment that the boards "*communicate over a spi - > rf chip*", I believe that the boards have no direct electrical connection between them, and *only* use an RF link. If that is not correct and if the two MCU are actually directly connected, then additional points from [another answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/463866) become possible too.)

> Both of them will only start properly around 10-20% of the time.

1. If `C10` and `C11` (2 x 0.1uF) are the only power decoupling, that is insufficient. See the "[STM32L0 Getting Started](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00112257.pdf)" document for more details. I have seen situations where boards with inadequate decoupling work correctly only with a JTAG debugger attached, because the debugger adds *additional* decoupling on the power rails, allowing the target board to then work.

   If there is extra power rail decoupling on your board (not shown on the public snippet of the schematic) which meets the requirements and physical placement shown in that document, then continue to the next point.
2. No external pull-up resistor is needed on NRST. What happens if you remove it?
3. NRST can be driven low by the MCU itself. When the MCU fails to start on your boards, is NRST being driven low by the MCU?
4. > I know I can use a POR supervisor and that should fix it

   Have you tried adding a POR supervisor, to see whether that does actually help to make the start-up reliable, without an STLink attached? If that does help, it would point towards an issue with reset / power rail ramp-up etc.
5. You mention reset and BOR, but there are other reasons why MCUs can fail to execute their internal code. Therefore the problem may be elsewhere.

   I can't see the full external connections due to the lack of full schematic, but for example, an external device powered from a different voltage source to the MCU can cause startup problems, by forcing MCU pins outside the MCU voltage rails. That's just one example.

   Since there is no previous working prototype, I would suggest **going back completely to square one**. Take one of the existing boards, disconnect all external active devices (e.g. RF comms IC and anything else connected via SPI) by cutting PCB tracks if necessary, and convert that one board to become a minimal test board, just with decoupling capacitors. Add just one LED + resistor (if it doesn't have one) and load a simple "blink LED" firmware.

   Does *that* start and blink the LED reliably, without any STLink attached?

   - No? That's unfortunate, but you have just simplified your "problem space" significantly. Review the "[STM32L0 Getting Started](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00112257.pdf)" document for the minimal requirements. There should be no places where your (now-minimal) board differs from the minimal setup shown there.
   - Yes? Then you now know that the MCU start-up was being affected not by *reset*, but by something *external to the MCU* on your board (something which you have disconnected). You can now investigate those areas (not shown on the public snippet of the schematic).

Comment: When the OP writes, "Both of them will only start properly around 10-20% of the time," I'm wondering if "start properly" is really about "start up AND communicate properly." It's possible that both start up (one on battery, the other on a slowly powering bench supply) and that the problem is really about the timing between them and the software that isn't handling varying power-up delays correctly. Just my thought in the mix. I like the rest you talked about, though.

Comment: @jonk - Thanks for the comment. I hadn't realised the possible interpretation you suggested about startup being a communications issue. If that is the intended meaning by the OP, then I haven't addressed it in my answer. Let's see if the OP can clarify. Thanks again for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I am really wondering if these two MCU boards are interconnected by some hardwired connections that route from one MCU to the other. If you do then your turn on problems probably stem from those hard wired connections.

When you are trying to start up the two MCUs that are on separate power systems invariably one of them is still powered down while the other is starting to come up. If there is a signal wire from the one that is just starting to power up that starts to going high that signal wire can be attempting to forward bias the input protection diodes on the MCU that is still powered down. Leakage current into the powered down MCU can cause all sorts unexpected behaviors. That could include disruption of the reset circuitry, latchup and disturbance of any on-chip charge pumps and substrate bias generators.

Some things that you could try:

1. Experiment to see what happens when both boards are powered from the same power supply.
2. Study if it is possible to setup the reset controls of both MCUs to be tied together and reset together.
3. Look over the design to see if you can arrange that all hardwired signal lines from MCU to MCU are all designed to startup at a low level until both MCUs are out of reset.
4. Consider the possibility to power gate one MCU and keep it unpowered until the MCU designated as the master has come up and initialized all the interface connections between boards. Only then allow the other MCU to power up under controlled conditions.